# Why is the derrivative of a displacement at the end of a rod equal to 0?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method

[image]

I'm studying a book on finite elements method and well, simply, I don't understand how they get this boundary condition.

Answer (score 2):

if we integrate the differential equation:
$$ \int_{L}^0 (AE \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-q=0) dx \quad \text{we get} \ AE \frac{du}{dx}-qx=c $$
By inspection we note c is zero and strain is proprtional to qx: $$ \quad \frac{du}{dx}\propto qx  $$

Note the strain du/dx is zero at L and maximum at x=0 due to triangular loading starting from zero at L and ending at qL at x=0

Answer (score -1):

It is not a typo so you can disregard the previous answer. This is not a bending problem, it is normally-loaded element. 
The first boundary condition just means that the displacement at the fixed end is zero. du/dx is the strain, therefore the second boundary condition simply means that the strain at the free end of the rod is zero.

Cheers

Comment: du/dx is the rate of change of strain.

Comment: @TigerGuy Your comment (and you answer) are both wrong. du/dx is the *strain*, not the rate of change of strain.

Comment: no, u is the strain.  Which is why u(0) = 0.  du/dx is clearly the derivative.  Source:  I looked it up.

Comment: Can you link the source where you looked it up? I thought u is the displacement... (which works with it as zero at the LHS)

Comment: @JonathanRSwift, from googling du/dx strain, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-080j-structural-mechanics-fall-2013/course-notes/MIT2_080JF13_Lecture2.pdf

Comment: @Tiger Guy - first page, just above equation 2.1 “  The displacement at the fixed end x = 0 of the rod is zero, u(x = 0)”. u is displacement. It says it in the document you linked...

Comment: Keep looking, it describes the derivative. If U(x) = something, then du/dx is the derivative.

Answer (score -2):

That equation means the rate of change of the strain (the derivative) at length L = 0.  This is because they have defined the force as being evenly distributed along the length of the bar.  As such, the strain along the bar will increase as the distance from the support descreases.  At the unsupported end, the force does not have anything additive to it from the forces past it, so the rate of change of strain = 0.